# Choice of version in Azure Artifact

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

In my MVC app, Azure artifact is used to manage packages, feed has ‘Microsoft.ApplicationInsights’ version ‘2.1.0’ in it. Now I need to include an upstream feed for new dev work, upstream feed has higher version of same package which is ‘2.20.0’. Will the build/restore choose the version specified in package.config file irrespective of versions available ?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the build/restore choose the version specified in package.config file irrespective of versions available ?

The answer is yes.

> NuGet Package Restore installs all of a project's dependencies listed
> in either the project file or packages.config

Check the document [Restore packages using Package Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) for some more details.